# Sidekiq consumes too much memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am using Sidekiq with God in my Rails app. I am using Passenger and Nginx.

I see many processes (30-50) running by sidekiq which consume about 1000MB of RAM.

Processes like:

- sidekiq 3.4.1 my_app_name [0 of 1 busy] - about 30 processes.
- ruby /home/myuser/.rvm/ruby-2.1.5/bin/sidekiq --environment ... - about 20 processes.

How to tell sidekiq to not run so many threads.

my config for sidekiq (config/sidekiq.yml):

```
---
:concurrency: 1
:queues:
  - default
  - mailer
```

and config for sidekiq for god:

```
num_workers = 1

num_workers.times do |num|
  God.watch do |w|
    ...

    w.start = "bundle exec sidekiq --environment #{rails_env} --config #{rails_root}/config/sidekiq.yml --daemon --logfile #{w.log}"
```

Comment: If you start sidekiq without using god do you get the same behaviour?

Comment: if I run in command line:

`bundle exec sidekiq -e beta -c 1 -C /../config/sidekiq.yml -d -L /../log/sidekiq.log`  then it starts 10 processes `sidekiq 3.4.1 my_app_name [0 of 1 busy]`. But I say -c 1 so I expect it runs one process.

Comment: without god it works fine.

Comment: Only one process is started?

Comment: if sidekiq is running without god then htop shows 10 processes.

Comment: Possibly can't read the config file from here `-C /../config/sidekiq.yml`

Comment: Threads look like processes in htop. Press Shift-H to show only true processes.

Comment: thanks. Those are threads (not processes) of the main process.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with "--daemon" (or "-d") parameter which runs it as a daemon. No need to run it as daemon. Just remove this parameter.